# This code should implement the Pascal's triangle using a 2D ArrayList, but the values for the input aren't passing through

Tags: java

According to Pascal's triangle,the value of every number is nCr where n is the row number and r the column number.

The problem seems to be where I pass the values to the arraylist, it doesn't show errors but it doesn't do anything either.

```
import java.util.*;


class arl5
{ public static void main(String []ar)
{ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> al = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("Enter no. of rows: ");
 int k= sc.nextInt();

 for(int m=0;m<k; m++)
 { al.add(new ArrayList<Integer>()); //initialize column list
}




for ( int i=0; i<al.size();i++ )
    { for ( int j=0; j<al.get(i).size(); j++)
        { int n = ncr(i,j);
          al.get(i).add(2);
          System.out.print(al.get(i).get(j)+" ");
        }
    }


}

public static int fact(int s) 
{ int fact =1;
  for(int i=0;i<s;i++)
  fact*=i;
  return fact;
}

public static int ncr(int n, int r)
{ int sub = fact(n-r) * fact(r);
  int f= fact(n)/sub;
  return f;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are asking the use for the number of rows, you should be providing an input bound or switching to longs or BigInteger. The results in the table overflow ints with an input of only 35, but the intermediate calculations overflow on row 14, since fact(14-1) is greater than 4 billion. Try calculating using the "add two above" method (see below) instead of actually calculating the combination values.

Now onto your problem. In your `for` loop in `main` that does all the assigning of values for each of the combinations, you calculate the combination and store it in a variable called `n`, then add the constant `2` to the ArrayList. You calculate the combination but then never use it.

Add Two Above method (in case you don't know):
Given:

```
      1
    1   1
  1   2   1
_   _   _   _
```

The first and last blanks on any row are 1.

The middle blanks are equivalent to the sum of the two numbers above the blank

So the last row would be:

```
1, since it is the first blank in a row
3, since 1 + 2 is 3
3, since 2 + 1 is 3
1, since it is the last blank in a row
```